# Magento 2 Parent category not assigned to subcategory when programatically creating

Tags: magento-2.1, category

I tried to create categories and subcategories pro-grammatically.

This is my code

```
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
enter code here
$cat_2 = "new_cat";
$name_2 = ucfirst($cat_2);
$url=strtolower($cat_2);
$cleanurl = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', '', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', '', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($url))))));
$categoryFactory=$objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
/// Add a new sub category under category id 3
$categoryTmp = $categoryFactory->create();
$categoryTmp->setName($name_2);
$categoryTmp->setIsActive(true);
$categoryTmp->setUrlKey($cleanurl);
$categoryTmp->setData('description', 'description');
//echo "In IF".$cat_vals[1];
$categoryTmp->setParentId(3);
$mediaAttribute = array ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail');
$categoryTmp->setImage('/m2.png', $mediaAttribute, true, false);
// Path pub/media/catalog/category/m2.png
$categoryTmp->setStoreId($storeId);
$categoryTmp->setPath($rootCat->getPath());
$categoryTmp->save();
```

When i run this script the category is adding but category is not created under categor id 3.

What is the issue i am facing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add new sub category please look into below code.

```
$parentCategory = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load(3);
$parentPath = $parentCategory->getPath();
$newCategory = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
$newCategory->setPath($parentPath);
$newCategory->setName($categoryName);
$newCategory->setUrlKey($this->productUrlFilter->formatUrlKey($name));
$newCategory->setIsActive(1);
$newCategory->setIsAnchor(1);
$newCategory->setParentId($parentCategory->getId());
$newCategory->setLevel($parentCategory->getLevel() + 1);
$newCategory->setStoreId(0);
$newCategory->save();
```